# Translate quantification into English and give the truth value

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

The problem is: $\exists x \in \mathbb{R} (x^3 = -1)$
I understand the following: 
$\exists x$ = There exists an $x$ 
$\in$ = shows the element before it is a member of a set after it 
$\mathbb{R}$ = Real number

This question doesn't make sense to me. If I try to translate it into English I get something like:

There exists an $x$ which is a member of a set of a real number $x^3 = -1$. I know that cant be correct, and also I'm not sure how to determine the truth value.

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your translation into English is basically correct:
*there exists a real number $x$ such that $x^3=-1$*

The statement is true since such $x$ does exist, take $x=-1$

Comment: What about the "∈", doesn't that mean there is an element of some sort? How can x be an element of x^3?

Comment: @user277005 it doesn't say it's an element of $x^3$. This is why you were assigned the problem. It does make sense, and this is what it means. It is an element of the set of real numbers.